# Link target to libraries

Tags: cmake, mingw

I have a "CMakified" version of CryptoPP and I am using CMake-GUI to create a MakeFile which ming-make could process as shown in the image below.

[image]

The "MakeFile" creation was successful but when I executed `mingw32-make.exe` I got below errors at the very end.

```
Linking CXX executable cryptest.exe
CMakeFiles\cryptest.dir/objects.a(test.cpp.obj):test.cpp:(.text+0x8e82): undefined reference to `setsockopt@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `socket@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x643): undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x6f0): undefined reference to `htonl@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x70a): undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x759): undefined reference to `htons@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x7f4): undefined reference to `bind@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x85b): undefined reference to `listen@8'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x909): undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x922): undefined reference to `gethostbyname@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x978): undefined reference to `htons@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xa18): undefined reference to `connect@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xaac): undefined reference to `accept@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xb58): undefined reference to `getsockname@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xbc6): undefined reference to `getpeername@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xc87): undefined reference to `send@16'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xd83): undefined reference to `recv@16'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xe25): undefined reference to `shutdown@8'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xe96): undefined reference to `ioctlsocket@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0xfbb): undefined reference to `select@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1010): undefined reference to `select@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x11a1): undefined reference to `select@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x11f6): undefined reference to `select@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x133f): undefined reference to `getservbyname@8'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1407): undefined reference to `ntohs@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1526): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x16cf): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x17fb): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x180f): undefined reference to `WSASetLastError@4'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1cfc): undefined reference to `WSARecv@28'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1d27): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1f61): undefined reference to `WSAGetOverlappedResult@20'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x1f8c): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x2397): undefined reference to `WSASend@28'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x23c1): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x24cc): undefined reference to `WSAEventSelect@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x2587): undefined reference to `WSAEnumNetworkEvents@12'
libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.obj):socketft.cpp:(.text+0x2a01): undefined reference to `WSAGetOverlappedResult@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [cryptest.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried adding `LDLIBS += -lws2_32` to the very end of the make file but this didn't help. I guess these errors are because the target link libraries are not mentioned in the make file but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Between `Linking CXX executable cryptest.exe`, and the raft of `unresolved reference` messages which follow, there ___should___ be an echo of the command line which failed; I guess CMake must have concealed it -- _bad, bad, BAD_ CMake. (If this is default CMake behaviour, then I consider it to be a critical CMake BUG). See, without that command line, we really have _no diagnostic information whatsoever_, to help us to pin down the problem.

Comment: FWIW, the conventional makefile variable for specifying libraries is `LIBS`, _not_ `LDLIBS`. Of course, CMake may not honour that convention -- I don't know, because I do not use CMake. If CMake _does_ use `LDLIBS`, is that a recursively expanded variable? If it isn't, then it needs to be ___fully___ specified ___before___ it's ever used; altering it at the end of the makefile may have no effect.

Comment: Have you written CMakeLists.txt or is it supplied by crypto++?

Comment: @Peter : I didn't write it. I got it from this [github project](https://github.com/mpapierski/cryptopp-cmake).

Comment: @KeithMarshall : Thankyou. Need to check if LDLIBS (or LIBS) is recursively expanded. Will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/mpapierski/cryptopp-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) should call

```
target_link_libraries(cryptopp ws2_32)
```

after command `ADD_LIBRARY` to resolve undefined references.

Comment: Thankyou, I am new to Cmake but I still prefer the traditional way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

After following Kieth's  comments above I figured out that neither LIBS nor LDLIBS are honoured by CMAKE. The variable to use is CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES. I did the below change in the CMAKE Advanced options:

[image]

I added `-lws2_32` at the very end and then generated the "MakeFile" .
This solved the issue.